# Container port forwarding

Tags: docker, google-cloud-run

I have a binary that listens on port `3000`, however, Google Cloud Run wants me to listen on the port defined by `$PORT`, that defaults to `8080`.

Is there a way to make my container bind to 8080 and then forward the incoming requests to 3000? for examplem by adding a short script and one line to my `Dockerfile`, it would make my container listen on 8080 and forward to my binary.

Comment: Can't you modify your application to default to 3000 but if $PORT is defined then use that port instead?

Comment: @codestation The question states that this is a binary, presumably the OP is unable to change the port.

Comment: @dustin-ingram is correct. The `PORT` environment variable is system-specified in Cloud Run. The solution really needs to ensure that the container will accept traffic on whatever `PORT` value is specified by the service; it's just that currently this is always `8080` but that's not steadfast.

Answer (score 2):

The code below is untested, but the general idea is this:

1. Use a shell-based startup script
2. Enable iptables
3. Route traffic from srcPort to dstPort
4. Exec the original binary

In the Dockerfile, replace the `ENTRYPOINT` with a startup script:

```
FROM debian:9 # or another container that has iptables available
RUN apt-get install iptables
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT /bin/startup.sh /bin/original
```

And then write a startup script that enables iptables and forwards inbound traffic on 8080 to 3000 inside the container:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

sed -i 's/#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1/net.ipv4.ip_forward=1/g' /etc/sysctl.conf
sysctl -p
systemctl start iptables

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp --dport 8080 -j REDIRECT --to-port 3000


unshift 
exec "$@"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the script fails. (1) `debian:9` doesn't include `sysctl` but `debian:8` does; (2) I think (!?) you can't modify `net.ipv4.ip_forward` within the container if neither running the container as `--privileged` nor using `--sysctl=net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` (which he can't on Cloud Run); (3) you want to refresh packages before the install with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install iptables`. @steren -- hopefully you've a FR to permit port-forwarding|publishing in Cloud Run ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you can install a run a second process and start it along your main process then install and run socat using the following command:

```
socat tcp-listen:8080,fork,reuseaddr tcp-connect:localhost:3000
```

This way socat will bind to the 8080 port and send all the traffic to the port 3000 where your binary is listening.

Outside of Cloud Run: If you cannot touch your image nor your container then you can still run socat on an additional container, for example:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  proxy:
    image: alpine/socat:1.0.3
    command: tcp-listen:8080,fork,reuseaddr tcp-connect:myservice:3000
    networks:
      - mynet
networks:
  mynet:
    external: true
```

Where `mynet` is the network where your binary is running and `myservice` is the service name of your binary.

Comment: Have you tested and verified this on Google Cloud Run?

Comment: @JohnHanley, no, but the first option should work just fine (additional process to redirect traffic), else something in Cloud Run is broken (i have used socat sucessfully in the past with docker containers). Of course, if everything else fails OP can hexedit the binary to change the port number (assuming the binary isn't signed/obfuscated).

Comment: I do not think the second part of your answer is possible with Cloud Run. Although Cloud Run is running a container, it is not a Docker container platform. The listening port (one port) for the entire container is controlled by Google. No access to Docker networks by name, etc. The address of another container would be unknown. How many containers are running at the same time is unknown (at this time). Cloud Run is designed as an HTTP Request / Response system that scales based upon requests per second.

Comment: @john-hanley is correct that you cannot (although it's a good solution) run a 'sidecar'-like container on Cloud Run to proxy the traffic (it's something Google should consider particularly as this is (a) going to be a reasonably common issue; (b) the underlying model is a Kubernetes Pod and this is a common pattern with Kubernetes.

Comment: While running `socat` in the same container may solve the problem, and running some form of proxy in the container *may* be the only solution, it's counter to good practice to run multiple processes in a single container.